# Google Analytics on Android

Tags: android, mobile, google-analytics, adsense

There is a specific and official analytics SDK for native Android apps (note that I'm not talking about webpages in apps on a phone). This library basically sends pages and events to Google Analytics and you can view your analytics in exactly the same dashboard as for websites. Since my background is apps rather than websites, and since a lot of the Google Analytics terminology seems particularly inapplicable to a native app, I need some pointers. Please discuss my remarks, provide some clarification where you think I'm off-track, and above all share good experiences!

### 1. Page Views

Pages mostly can match different Activities (and Dialogs) being displayed.  Activities can be visible behind non-full-screen Activities however, though only the top-level Activity can be interacted. This sort-off clashes with a "(page) view". **update ->** Read http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/analytics-for-android-apps.html and accept it.

You'd also want at least one page view for each visit and therefore put one page view tracker in the Application class. However this does not constitute a window or sorts. Usually an Activity will open at the same time, so the time spent on that page will have been 0. This will influence your "time spent" statistics. How are these counted anyway?

Moreover, there is a loose coupling between the Activities, by means of Intents. A user can, much like on any website, step in at any Activity, although usually this then concerns resuming the application where he left off. This makes that the hierarchy of Activities usually is very flat. And since there are no url's involved. What meaning would using slashes in page titles have, such as "/Home"? All pages would appear on an equal level in the reports, so no content drilldown.

Non-unique page views seem to be counted as some kind of indicator of successfulness: how often does the visitor revisit the page. When the user rotates the screen however usually an Activity is recreated, thus making it a new page view. This happens a lot. Maybe a well-thought-through placement of the call might solve this, or placing several, I'm not sure.

How to deal with Page Views?

### 2. Events

I'd say there are two sorts:

- A user event
- Something that happened, usually as an indirect consequence of the above.

The latter particularly is giving me headaches. First of all, many events aren't written in code any more, but pieced logically together by means of Intents. This means that there is no place to put the analytics call. You'd either have to give up this advantage and start doing it the old-fashioned way in favor of good analytics, or, just be missing some events.

Secondly, as a developer you're not so much interested in when a user clicks a button, but if the action that should have been performed really was performed and what the result was. There seems to be no clear way to get resulting data into Google Analytics (what's up with the integers? I want to put in Strings!).

The same that applies to the flat pages hierarchy, also goes for the event categories. You could do "vertical" categories (topically, that is), but some code is shared "horizontally" and the tracking will be equally shared. Just as with the Intents mechanism, inheritance makes it hard for you to put the tracking in the right places at all times. And I can't really imagine "horizontal" categories. Unless you start making really small categories, such as all the items form the same menu in one category, I have a hard time grasping the concept.

Finally, how do you deal with cancelling? Usually you both have an explicit cancel mechanism by ways of a button, as well as the implicit cancel when the "back"-button is pressed to leave the activity and there were no changes. The latter also applies to "saves", when the back button is pressed and there ARE changes. How are you consequently going to catch all these if not by doing all the "back"-button work yourself?

How to deal with events?

### 3. Goals

For goal types I have choice of: URL Destination, Time on Site, and Pages/Visit. Most apps don't have a funnel that leads the user to some "registration done" or "order placed" page. Apps have either already been bought (in which case you want to stimulate the user to love your app, so that he might bring on new buyers) or are paid for by in-app ads. So URL Destination is not a very important goal.

Time on Site also seems troublesome. First, I have some doubt on how this would be measured. Second, I don't necessarily want my user to spend a lot of time in my already paid app, just be active and content. Equivalently, why not mention how frequent a user uses your app?

Regarding Pages/Visit I already mentioned how screen orientation changes blow up the page view numbers.

In an app I'd be most interested in events/visit to measure the user's involvement/activity. If he's intensively using the app then he must be loving it right?

Furthermore, I also have some small funnels (that do not lead to conversion though) that I want to see streamlined. In my mind those funnels would end in events rather than page views but that seems not to be possible.

I could also measure clickthroughs on in-app ads, but then I'd need to track those as Page Views rather than Events, in view of "URL Destination".

What are smart goals for apps and how can you fit them on top of Analytics?

### 4. Optimisation

Is there a smart way to manually do what "Website Optimiser" does for websites? Most importantly, how would I track different landing page designs? **update ->** Seems I could use the Custom Variables for that. More details are still welcome.

### 5. Traffic Sources

Referrals deal with installation time referrals, if you're smart enough to get them included. But perhaps I'd also want to get some data which third-party app sends users to my app to perform some actions (this app interoperability is possible via Intents).

Many of the terminologies related to "Traffic Sources" seem totally meaningless and there is no possibility of connecting in AdSense.

What are smart uses of this data?

### 6. Visitors

Of the "Browser capabilities", "Network Properties" and "Mobile" tabs, many things are pointless as they have no influence on / relation with my mostly offline app that won't use flash anyway. Only if you drill down far enough, can you get to OS versions, which do matter a lot. I even forgot where you could check what exact Android devices visited.

What are smart uses of this data? How can you make the relevant info more prominent?

### 7. Other

No in-page analytics. I have to register my app as a web-url (What!?)?

Comment: Great question, but belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: Not sure. I seriously thought of putting it at StackOverflow, most of my questions go there. I tried to write up my question as non-technical, and explain some of the technical aspects if I had to touch them. In essence I'm asking about ways-of-working that are much closer to webmaster's insights rather than programmers. This is definetely about usage, not about how to technically insert analytics into my app. It is about making good decisions to do so, and learning better ways to do it.

Comment: If you have not done so already, you might wish to read http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/analytics-for-android-apps.html

Comment: Mark, I had, though not recently. Now that I read it again it's a must-read and it is quite complete on a technical level, however for me it falls short on showing how to work with Google Analytics itself. To be clear, I've already implemented most of this in my app. In my question I've tried to list some of the details and angles the blogpost does not mention. The post annoyingly is also very down-to-earth: "it’s going to be up to you to decide what a “pageview” means". Somebody has to be able to do better than that! I'm interested in finding out what exactly has worked for other people.

Comment: Take the media player example in that blogpost for instance. It doesn't come across as a particular good one. A category is assigned, but it is a small group here (only part of a page) and I'm not sure if you can regroup events from different categories in the dashboard later on. Having a time span to insert as int also seems rare in an app. These buttons happen to have onCLick code, but an OptionsMenu could exist solely out of Intents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics is pretty good for basic tracking of Android app usage. If you need more mobile-app-focused analytics you may also want to look at these:

http://www.flurry.com

http://www.capptain.com

A benefit of these over Google Analytics is that they are designed to track mobile app usage, rather than web site usage, so are more specific in what they do, but to be honest there's always going to be work for you to do to define what actions within your app matter to you enough to track - that's more about the needs of the business, than the technology.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about capptain.com. Still want to leave the question open till some more experiences have been answered.

Answer (score 1):

I am not convinced with google analytics for tracking our application. Because as per my requirement i would like to get the error or crash report from my launching application in market. From this error report i could see the stack trace of the crash so that i can fix my bug. But from google analytics i am not sure how to get these details, I would suggest the best crash report trackr is Acra you will get more info here http://code.google.com/p/acra/

If someone know how to get these crash report using Google analytics please share.

Comment: If you're talking about just crash reports then Android market will show you reports from a published app. Check [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/05/google-feedback-for-android.html).
But having used ACRA myself, I agree that there is a lot more that you can do with ACRA!

Answer (score 1):

I've no analytics experience but after searching a while i found this page [Flurry-vs-Mixpanel-vs-Google-Mobile-Analytics-who-wins-Why](http://www.quora.com/Flurry-vs-Mixpanel-vs-Google-Mobile-Analytics-who-wins-Why) and i think you can find useful information and I also decided to use *Flurry*